# Self Join With Multiple Conditions

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, self-join

I'm using mysql to storing my chemical analysis. And filtering the results with html/php and to generate the query to fetch results I want. Now things getting complex for me and I'm trying to self join the table to apply all the filters.

My table desing is like that with more than 50k rows.

```
+--------+---------+-------------+----------------+
| Column |  Type   |    Index    |                |
+--------+---------+-------------+----------------+
| RID    | int     | primary_key | auto increment |
| ID     | int     | index       |                |
| Type   | int     |             |                |
| Order  | int     |             |                |
| Num    | int     |             |                |
| Val1   | decimal |             |                |
| Val2   | decimal |             |                |
+--------+---------+-------------+----------------+
```

Every sample has an **ID**, different **types** and **order**. **Val1** and **Val2** are the results of **Num** type analyse. There 42 different Num by now.

For example If my filters are like that,

```
Select Types (1,3,9)
Select ANum (0,5)
Type 1, Num 5 should be bigger than 10 In Val2
Type 1, Num 5, should be smaller than 30 In Val2
Type 3, Num 0, should be smaller than 8 In Val1
```

I'm using that query to produce results.

```
SELECT analyse.* FROM analyse 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT ID FROM analyse WHERE Type = 1 AND Num = 5 AND Val2 < 30) AS a1 ON a1.SID = analyse.SID 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT SID FROM  WHERE Type = 1 AND Num = 5 AND Val2 > 10) AS a2 ON a2.SID = analyse.SID
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT SID FROM analyse WHERE Type = 3 AND Num = 0 AND Val1 > 8) AS a3 ON a2.SID = analyse.SID 
WHERE Type IN (1,3,9) AND Num IN (0,5) ORDER BY ID, Type, Order, Num ASC

+-----+------+-------+---------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| ID  | Type | Order | Val1[Num[0]]  | Val2[Num[0]] | Val1[Num[5]] | Val2[Num[5]] |
+-----+------+-------+---------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| ... | ...  | ...   | ...           | ...          | ...          | ...          |
| 118 | 1    | 1     | 10.9000       | 2.2083       | 3.5056       | 15.2627      |
| 118 | 1    | 2     | 9.5000        | 1.9246       | 2.0305       | 11.7049      |
| 118 | 1    | 3     | 7.9000        | 1.6005       | 2.4274       | 16.6597      |
| 118 | 2    | 1     | 10.9000       | 2.2083       | 3.5056       | 15.2627      |
| 118 | 3    | 2     | 20.4000       | 4.1329       | 2.8187       | 22.9676      |
| 118 | 4    | 3     | 28.3000       | 5.7334       | 2.7094       | 29.6273      |
| 119 | 1    | 1     | 27.2000       | 6.8635       | 0.5506       | 14.9084      |
| 119 | 1    | 2     | 25.9000       | 6.5355       | 0.4249       | 10.9550      |
| 119 | 3    | 1     | 27.2000       | 6.8635       | 0.5506       | 14.9084      |
| 119 | 3    | 2     | 53.1000       | 13.3989      | 0.4893       | 25.8634      |
| ... | ...  | ...   | ...           | ...          | ...          | ...          |
+-----+------+-------+---------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Desired output should be like this. However, since there are other Val1 and Val2 values has same ID, same Type but different order, INNER JOIN doesn't work as expected I guess. There are always bigger and smaller values appear than my filter. Some of them never shown.

Sorry If it's too long. I can't find the correct statment or structure. Any advice?

Edit: Sorry. I forgot to mention all other the data must be shown of IDs. That's why I'm trying to use join.

Comment: Can you list the structure or is the data it... you reference an "SType" in your where clause.  Also, you are looking for results on a per "ID" basis?, and each chemical analysis is expected in a specific ORDER??? such as condition 1 must be found before condition 2 and etc for condition 3?  From those that all 3 criteria are met are... those are the final records you want?

Comment: @DRapp I wrote the query in here so SType is miswritten. It's "Type". As I said need all data of an ID, which passes the filter. As an example If my condition for "type 1, num 5 smaller than 20 val2", 29.62, 22,96 still will be shown for Val2. Because there are parameters passes the filter for ID 118.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem with querying same Nums and Types together instead of fetching them with seperate joins. By that way, no other data for same Num and Type can pass the filter.

For that conditions

```
Select Types (1,3,9)
Select ANum (0,5)
Type 1, Num 5 should be bigger than 10 In Val2
Type 1, Num 5, should be smaller than 30 In Val2
Type 3, Num 0, should be smaller than 8 In Val1
```

Query should be this,

```
SELECT analyse.* FROM analyse 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT ID FROM analyse WHERE Type = 1 AND Num = 5 AND Val2 < 30 AND Val2 > 10) AS a1 ON a1.SID = analyse.SID 
(SELECT SID FROM analyse WHERE Type = 3 AND Num = 0 AND Val1 > 8) AS a3 ON a2.SID = analyse.SID 
WHERE Type IN (1,3,9) AND Num IN (0,5) ORDER BY ID, Type, Order, Num ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

So, your requirement on the table is

```
Select Types (1,3,9)
Select Num (0,5)
Type 1, Num 5 should be bigger than 10 In Val2
Type 1, Num 5, should be smaller than 30 In Val2
Type 3, Num 0, should be smaller than 8 In Val1
```

That's basically 4 different criterias which need to be evaluated (Type, num, Val1, Val2)

While there might be "better" solutions (in Terms of performance or easier to read code) the easiest approach is to create distinct pairs of conditions, which should be fine unless you deal with millions of records.

Out of your requirement, I would derrive that you need the following row-sets to be fetched:

```
1.) Type = 1, Num = 5, Val2 > 10
2.) Type = 1, Num = 5, Val2 < 30
3.) Type = 3, Num = 0, Val1 < 8
4.) Type = 9
```

So, that would be a union of "4 explicit" queries:

```
SELECT * FROM analyse WHERE Type = 1 AND Num = 5 AND Val2 > 10
UNION
SELECT * FROM analyse WHERE Type = 1 AND Num = 5 AND Val2 < 10
UNION
SELECT * FROM analyse WHERE Type = 3 AND Num = 0 AND Val1 < 8
UNION
SELECT * FROM analyse WHERE Type = 9
```

To filter the final result by id, you can simply use:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM analyse WHERE Type = 1 AND Num = 5 AND Val2 > 10
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM analyse WHERE Type = 1 AND Num = 5 AND Val2 < 10
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM analyse WHERE Type = 3 AND Num = 0 AND Val1 < 8
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM analyse WHERE Type = 9
) as tempTable WHERE id = 118
```

- or just append the id to each independent query.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess I forgot to mention. All other data must be shown with filtered ID's.

Comment: Thanks, I will try.

Comment: UNION will create serious performance issues I think. My table already has 50k rows and I don't want to filter one id each time.